# error using std::make_shared abstract class instantiation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm going to omit quite bit of code because these are some rather large objects, and my question really just concerns the operation of std::make_shared .  I have an object in namespace SYNC called called D3D11Shader. This has a **static** function called,

```
SYNC::D3D11Shader * SYNC::D3D11Shader::CreateInstance(const std::string & s)
```

which will take a string index and return a pointer to an instance of a shader that is derived from SYNC::D3D11Shader. At one point i started using smart pointers to automate deallocation of these within the vector that held all these shaders. However, when i go to do this,

```
 std::shared_ptr<SYNC::D3D11Shader> shaderPtr;
 // ... verification of index and other initialization happens here
 // so i am unable to initialize it in it's constructor
 shaderPtr = std::make_shared<SYNC::D3D11Shader>(SYNC::D3D11Shader::CreateShader(shaderName));
```

the compiler errors saying that i am trying to instanciate an instance of D3D11Shader in this line which is an abstract class. I thought all make_shared did was return an instance of std::shared_ptr. The CreateInstance function never tries to make an instance of this class, just objects that derive and implement it. I was not getting this error before using this function and the smart pointers. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Check the documentation of make_shared http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410595.aspx

Comment: Well shoot, key phrase in the defintion being, "Constructs an object." is there anyway to simply set a shared_ptr to a pointer after initialization?

Comment: Use shared_ptr's constructor directly `shared_ptr<SYNC::D3D11Shader> ptr(your_pointer_here);`, or `ptr.reset(your_pointer_here);` if you have an existing one.

Comment: I think the best solution would be to rewrite the interface of `CreateInstance` to return a shared pointer. Then you can use `make_shared` inside *that* code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you can't use the constructor of `shared_ptr`, use its [`reset` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) to give it ownership of a new object:

```
std::shared_ptr<SYNC::D3D11Shader> shaderPtr;
shaderPtr.reset(SYNC::D3D11Shader::CreateShader(shaderName));
```

The reason `make_shared<T>` is not appropriate for this situation is because it constructs a new `T`, forwarding its arguments to its constructor. You've already constructed an object, though, so you just want to give ownership to your shared pointer.

I highly recommend not returning a raw pointer from `CreateShader` though. You're relying on the caller of `CreateShader` to know to either wrap it up in a smart pointer or call `delete` on it. You'd be better off returning a `unique_ptr` directly, to pass ownership to the client, and then they can make a `shared_ptr` out of it if they like. See the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<SYNC::D3D11Shader> uniquePtr(SYNC::D3D11Shader::CreateShader(shaderName));
// If you want a shared_ptr:
std::shared_ptr<SYNC::D3D11Shader> sharedPtr(std::move(uniquePtr));
```

Or simply:

```
std::shared_ptr<SYNC::D3D11Shader> sharedPtr = SYNC::D3D11Shader::CreateShader(shaderName);
```

If you're going to use smart pointers, use them. :)

Comment: @FatalCatharsis I added some comments on how you could change your design.

Comment: Never knew about using reset for abstract classes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough:

```
shaderPtr.reset(SYNC::D3D11Shader::CreateShader(shaderName));
```

You can see the different variants of the `reset` member function [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset).